# Is it possible to reverse the traversing order of index in MongoDB to keep performance but ingore creating similar index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Collection `c` has hundred thousands of documents, and every document has two fields (`x` and `y`). Below are some examples.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a0736f"), "x" : 1, "y" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07370"), "x" : 2, "y" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07371"), "x" : 3, "y" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07372"), "x" : 3, "y" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07373"), "x" : 3, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07374"), "x" : 4, "y" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07376"), "x" : 5, "y" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07377"), "x" : 5, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07378"), "x" : 5, "y" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07379"), "x" : 6, "y" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a0737a"), "x" : 6, "y" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a0737b"), "x" : 6, "y" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a0737c"), "x" : 7, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a0737d"), "x" : 8, "y" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a0737e"), "x" : 9, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a0737f"), "x" : 9, "y" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07380"), "x" : 10, "y" : 11 }
```

**The values of `x` and `y` is number type, but random.**
Now I want to find no more than 3 documents whose values are `least` but `larger than or equal to` **{x:5, y:3}**.
Regulation to compare two documents by function:

```
int compareDocument(doc1, doc2) {
    var result;
    if (doc1.x > doc2.x) {
        result = 1;
    } else if (doc1.x == doc2.x) {
        if (doc1.y > doc2.y) {
            result = 1;
        } else if (doc1.y == doc2.y) {
            result = 0;
        } else {
            result = -1;
        }
    } else {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It must be executed in high performance. The method I have is:

```
> db.c.ensureIndex({x:1,y:1},{name:"asc"});
> db.c.find().hint("asc").min({x:5,y:3}).limit(3);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07377"), "x" : 5, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07378"), "x" : 5, "y" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07379"), "x" : 6, "y" : 2 }
> db.c.find().hint("asc").min({x:5,y:3}).limit(3).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor asc",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 3,
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "start" : {
                        "x" : 5,
                        "y" : 3
                },
                "end" : {
                        "x" : {
                                "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        "y" : {
                                "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                }
        },
        "server" : "Mars-PC:27017"
}
```

**Above only 3 documents scanned.**

Again, I want to find no more than 3 documents whose values are `largest` but `less than or equal to` **{x:5, y:3}**.
**Is it possible to do this by using above index `asc`, or something else without creating new index, but keep high perforance?**

I can't find it. What I can do is to create another similar index to fultill it.

```
> db.c.ensureIndex({x:-1, y:-1},{name:"desc"});
> db.c.find().hint("desc").min({x:5, y:3}).limit(3);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07377"), "x" : 5, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07376"), "x" : 5, "y" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fecab45ae4ec5280a07374"), "x" : 4, "y" : 2 }
> db.c.find().hint("desc").min({x:5, y:3}).limit(3).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor desc",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 3,
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "start" : {
                        "x" : 5,
                        "y" : 3
                },
                "end" : {
                        "x" : {
                                "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        "y" : {
                                "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                }
        },
        "server" : "Mars-PC:27017"
}
```

Comment: Not too sure what is really being asked here. Why do you not just create one index and do your "sort" in reverse? That generally should be your preference in index selection before going to `.hint()`. MongoDB does not care about the order of creation other than it reflecting the "default" sort other when that index is selected. The same could be said of other modifiers which could really just be specified in the query.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, thanks for reply. I've updated the question. Please have a look. :)

Comment: Still don't get what you are trying to do. Note how the values returned show results where "y" is less than the `3` you specify in the cursor modifier. So I don't think you are even issuing the query that you want.

Comment: Essentially, you want to know which compound indexes support which kinds of sorts. This is covered as part of the [compound indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#index-ascending-and-descending) docs.