# mongoDB $sort inconsistent results

Tags: mongodb, go, database

I have the following query in go lang which works fine:

```
query["name"] = bson.M{"$regex": searchStr, "$options": "i"}
query["likes"] = userSession.Id
c.Find(query).Skip(0).Limit(2).Select(bson.M{"name":1, "profile":1, "description":1, "user_id":1, "likes":1}).Sort("-pro", "-check").All(&business);
```

Then I tried to write the same query using the aggregation framework:

```
query["name"] = bson.M{"$regex": searchStr, "$options": "i"}
query["likes"] = userSession.Id
oe := bson.M{
    "$match" :query,
}
oa := bson.M{
    "$project": bson.M {"pro": 1, "check": 1, "name":1, "profile":1, "description":1, "user_id":1, "likes":1, "nrLikes": bson.M{ "$size": "$likes" }, "city": 1, "country": 1, "industry": 1},
}
ol := bson.M{
    "$limit" :pageSize,
}
os := bson.M{
    "$skip" :skips,
}
or := bson.M{
    "$sort" : bson.M {"pro": -1, "check": -1},
}

pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{oe, oa, or, os, ol  })

pipe.All(&business)
```

The second query works fine 90% of the time, but 10% of the times it returns a different order for results.

Any thoughts?

Later edit: Here are the resuls

```
[]bson.M{
{
    "description": "<p>sasdfdasf</p>",
    "profile":     []interface {}{
        "rKwMmXPWheGczwvGn2TzSRU7jRorhorKwMmXPWheGczwvGn2TzSRU7jRorho=0.jpg",
    },
    "likes": []interface {}{
        "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    },
    "nrLikes":  int(1),
    "name":     "ediloc.com2",
    "city":     "Calimanesti",
    "industry": "Automotive",
    "_id":      "Yo\xd4f\x1a\xa9Q|w\tG^",
    "user_id":  "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    "country":  "Romania",
},
{
    "_id":         "Yo\xc7\xd7\x1a\xa9Qy1['\xea",
    "user_id":     "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    "name":        "ediloc.com",
    "country":     "Romania",
    "description": "<p>a</p>",
    "profile":     []interface {}{
        "1ssSySNRZwGJJwqzXghL6qzAVfWZis1ssSySNRZwGJJwqzXghL6qzAVfWZis=1.jpg",
    },
    "likes": []interface {}{
        "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    },
    "nrLikes":  int(1),
    "city":     "Calimanesti",
    "industry": "Accounting",
},
}


[]bson.M{
{
    "likes": []interface {}{
        "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    },
    "_id":     "Yo\xd4f\x1a\xa9Q|w\tG^",
    "name":    "ediloc.com2",
    "city":    "Calimanesti",
    "country": "Romania",
    "profile": []interface {}{
        "rKwMmXPWheGczwvGn2TzSRU7jRorhorKwMmXPWheGczwvGn2TzSRU7jRorho=0.jpg",
    },
    "user_id":     "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    "industry":    "Automotive",,
    "nrLikes":     int(1),
},
{
    "_id":      "Yo\xc7\xd7\x1a\xa9Qy1['\xea",
    "user_id":  "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    "industry": "Accounting",
    "profile":  []interface {}{
        "1ssSySNRZwGJJwqzXghL6qzAVfWZis1ssSySNRZwGJJwqzXghL6qzAVfWZis=1.jpg",
    },
    "likes": []interface {}{
        "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    },
    "nrLikes":     int(1),
    "name":        "ediloc.com",
    "city":        "Calimanesti",
    "country":     "Romania",
    "description": "<p>a</p>",
},
}


[]bson.M{
{
    "nrLikes":     int(1),
    "user_id":     "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    "description": "<p>a</p>",
    "profile":     []interface {}{
        "1ssSySNRZwGJJwqzXghL6qzAVfWZis1ssSySNRZwGJJwqzXghL6qzAVfWZis=1.jpg",
    },
    "country":  "Romania",
    "industry": "Accounting",
    "likes":    []interface {}{
        "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    },
    "_id":  "Yo\xc7\xd7\x1a\xa9Qy1['\xea",
    "name": "ediloc.com",
    "city": "Calimanesti",
},
{
    "name":        "ediloc.com2",
    "industry":    "Automotive",
    "description": "<p>sasdfdasf</p>",
    "likes":       []interface {}{
        "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    },
    "user_id": "Yo\xc7;\x1a\xa9Qy\b\xb8\xa2\xf9",
    "city":    "Calimanesti",
    "country": "Romania",
    "profile": []interface {}{
        "rKwMmXPWheGczwvGn2TzSRU7jRorhorKwMmXPWheGczwvGn2TzSRU7jRorho=0.jpg",
    },
    "nrLikes": int(1),
    "_id":     "Yo\xd4f\x1a\xa9Q|w\tG^",
},
}
```

Pro and check fields are in32, the documents with higher pro field number should have priority over the documents that have higher check fields.

Comment: What is the data type of your `pro` field? Can you include some example output where the sorting is incorrect? If the results aren't predictable it's likely you have mixed data types which sort according to [BSON Comparison/Sort Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#bson-types-comparison-order).

Comment: @Stennie I edited my question and added the output. Also the check and pro fields are both int32. And also keep in find that the first query using cursor.sort() works fine.

Comment: Have you altered the output? Unless I'm missing something it seems like the current result documents don't have the `pro` and `check` fields you are sorting on.

Comment: I just didn't put them in the project this time.

Comment: You can see here http://2message.com:8080/search/business?q=e if you refresh many times the page, the results are inconsistent.

One document has pro:1 and check: 0 and the other has pro:0 and check:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have your sort pipeline stage *before* your limit & skip stages. You can only reliably obtain the same results with limit/skip on sorted input.

**EDIT**

Realised that you are using `bson.M {"pro": -1, "check": -1}` to define your sort order. The iteration order of a map is unspecified in Go and can change. Hence this is probably why you are getting inconsistent results.

Try changing this to a `bson.D` so that the order of columns to sort by is maintained.

It make help to see how the query [Sort](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L2130) method constructs this from the strings you provide.

For your use case, you would change the `or` variable to:

```
or := bson.M{
    "$sort": bson.D{
        bson.DocElem{Name: "pro", Value: -1},
        bson.DocElem{Name: "check", Value: -1},
     },
}
```

Comment: Yes I am doing the sort before the skip and limit.

Comment: Sorry, you are indeed. I just read the declaration order, not the order they were passed to `c.Pipe`. As an aside, the recommendation is for limit before skip (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160037/skip-and-limit-in-aggregation-framework)). Don't think that will be your issue though.

Comment: I tried now, but it didn't change anything. 

One document has pro:1 and check: 0 and the other has pro:0 and check:1

you can see here: 2message.com:8080/search/business?q=e  if you refresh many times the page

Comment: Updated my answer, see if that helps

Comment: I never used bson.D, how should I write the above lines? I tried:

 `or := bson.D{
        "$sort" : []bson.D{
  {Name: "pro", Value: -1},
  {Name: "check", Value: -1}
 }` but didn't compile

Comment: Updated my answer with an example

Comment: Something that may be important to note: If you are sorting, make sure _at least one_ of your fields you are sorting by are _unique_, or you'll end up like me debugging for 3 hours trying to figure out why you have repeated results.