# Mongoose MongoDB GeoSpatial Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an `Item` collection which could hold thousands to hundreds of thousands of documents. On that collection, I want to perform Geospatial queries. Using Mongoose, there are two options - `find()` and the Aggregation Pipeline. I have displayed my implementations of both below:

#### Mongoose Model

To start, here are the relevant properties of my Mongoose Model:

```
// Define the schema
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // Firebase UID (in addition to the Mongo ObjectID)
    owner: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    // ... Some more fields
    numberOfViews: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    numberOfLikes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true, 
        default: 0
    },
    location: {
        type: {
            type: 'String',
            default: 'Point',
            required: true
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            required: true,
        },
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// 2dsphere index
itemSchema.index({ "location": "2dsphere" });

// Create the model
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

#### Find Query

```
// These variables are populated based on URL Query Parameters.
const match = {};
const sort = {};

// Query to make.
const query = {
    location: {
        $near: {
            $maxDistance: parseInt(req.query.maxDistance),
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [parseInt(req.query.lng), parseInt(req.query.lat)]
            }
        }
    },
    ...match
};

// Pagination and Sorting
const options = {
    limit: parseInt(req.query.limit),
    skip: parseInt(req.query.skip),
    sort
};

const items = await Item.find(query, undefined, options).lean().exec();

res.send(items);
```

#### Aggregation Pipeline

Suppose distance needed to be calculated:

```
// These variables are populated based on URL Query Parameters.
const query = {};
const sort = {};

const geoSpatialQuery = {
    $geoNear: {
        near: { 
            type: 'Point', 
            coordinates: [parseInt(req.query.lng), parseInt(req.query.lat)] 
        },
        distanceField: "distance",
        maxDistance: parseInt(req.query.maxDistance),
        query,
        spherical: true
    }
};

const items = await Item.aggregate([
    geoSpatialQuery,
    { $limit: parseInt(req.query.limit) },
    { $skip: parseInt(req.query.skip) },
    { $sort: { distance: -1, ...sort } } 
]).exec();

res.send(items);
```

#### Edit - Example Documented Amended

Here is an example of a document with all of its properties from the `Item` collection:

```
{
   "_id":"5cd08927c19d1dd118d39a2b",
   "imagePaths":{
      "standard":{
         "images":[
            "users/zbYmcwsGhcU3LwROLWa4eC0RRgG3/5cd08927c19d1dd118d39a2b/images/Image-aafe69c7-f93e-411e-b75d-319042068921-standard.jpg",
            "users/zbYmcwsGhcU3LwROLWa4eC0RRgG3/5cd08927c19d1dd118d39a2b/images/Image-397c95c6-fb10-4005-b511-692f991341fb-standard.jpg",
            "users/zbYmcwsGhcU3LwROLWa4eC0RRgG3/5cd08927c19d1dd118d39a2b/images/Image-e54db72e-7613-433d-8d9b-8d2347440204-standard.jpg",
            "users/zbYmcwsGhcU3LwROLWa4eC0RRgG3/5cd08927c19d1dd118d39a2b/images/Image-c767f54f-7d1e-4737-b0e7-c02ee5d8f1cf-standard.jpg"
         ],
         "profile":"users/zbYmcwsGhcU3LwROLWa4eC0RRgG3/5cd08927c19d1dd118d39a2b/images/Image-51318c32-38dc-44ac-aac3-c8cc46698cfa-standard-profile.jpg"
      },
      "thumbnail":"users/zbYmcwsGhcU3LwROLWa4eC0RRgG3/5cd08927c19d1dd118d39a2b/images/Image-51318c32-38dc-44ac-aac3-c8cc46698cfa-thumbnail.jpg",
      "medium":"users/zbYmcwsGhcU3LwROLWa4eC0RRgG3/5cd08927c19d1dd118d39a2b/images/Image-51318c32-38dc-44ac-aac3-c8cc46698cfa-medium.jpg"
   },
   "location":{
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         -110.8571443,
         35.4586858
      ]
   },
   "numberOfViews":0,
   "numberOfLikes":0,
   "monetarySellingAmount":9000,
   "exchangeCategories":[
      "Math"
    ],
   "itemCategories":[
      "Sports"
   ],
   "title":"My title",
   "itemDescription":"A description",
   "exchangeRadius":10,
   "owner":"zbYmcwsGhcU3LwROLWa4eC0RRgG3",
   "reports":[],
   "createdAt":"2019-05-06T19:21:13.217Z",
   "updatedAt":"2019-05-06T19:21:13.217Z",
   "__v":0
}
```

#### Questions

Based on the above, I wanted to ask a few questions.

1. Is there a performance difference between my implementations of the normal Mongoose Query and the use of the Aggregation Pipeline?
2. Is it correct to say that `near` and `geoNear` are pretty much similar to `nearSphere` when using the `2dsphere` index with GeoJSON - except that `geoNear` provides extra data and default limiting? That is, although having different units, both queries - *conceptually* - would show relevant data within a specific radius from some location, despite the fact the field is called `radius` for `nearSphere` and `maxDistance` with `near`/`geoNear`.
3. With my example above, how might the performance loss of using `skip` be mitigated but still be able to achieve pagination in both querying and aggregation?
4. The `find()` function allows an optional parameter to determine which fields will be returned. The Aggregation Pipeline takes a `$project` stage to do the same. Is there a specific order where `$project` should be used in the pipeline to optimize speed/efficiency, or does it not matter?

I hope this style of question is permitted as per the Stack Overflow rules. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a sample document of your collection please.
Aggregation pipeline is  kind of  data flow so data is filtered through the pipeline so its depend on your requiremnt.

Comment: @SheshanGamage Thank you for your comment. Please see the updated/edit to view the contents of an example document.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below query with 2dsphere indexing.I used the aggregation pipeline
for the below query.

```
db.items.createIndex({location:"2dsphere"})
```

While using aggregation pipeline it gives you more flexibility on the result set. Also aggregation pipeline will improve the performance on running geo related searches.

```
db.items.aggregate([
{
 $geoNear: {
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -110.8571443 , 35.4586858 ] },
    key: "location",
    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    minDistance: 2, 
    query: { "itemDescription": "A description" }
 }])
```

On your question on $skip below question will give you more insight on the $skip oepration
[$skip and $limit in aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160037/skip-and-limit-in-aggregation-framework)

You can use $project accordingly to your need. In our case we didnt had much of performance issue using $project over 10 million of data

Comment: Thank you. What is `key` for, and, according to the answer you linked, is it better to use `sort` as the stage prior to `limit`?

Comment: key is the field name of you    "location":{
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         -110.8571443,
         35.4586858
      ]
   }

yes it is always good to use limit at the end of the pipeline