# Filter by id in an array of object ids before populate mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have post schema like this

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, minlength: 2 },
  description: { type: String },
  categoryId: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "category" }],
});
```

I have to fetch random documents from the posts and populate all categories in it. What I have achieved so far is this

```
await Post.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "categories",
          localField: "categoryId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "categoryId",
        },
      },
    ]).sample(5)
```

**Need to do**

Suppose i have an **id** of a category in a variable ***catId***, what I need to do is to filter out those posts which contains this **id** in their array of categoryId before getting those random posts. By filtering out I mean i need random posts which has ***catId*** in their array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below :

```
Post.aggregate([
  /** Use match to Get docs where 'categoryId' has passed in value */
  {
    $match: {
      categoryId: catId /** Input 'catId', make sure you convert input request of string to 'ObjectId()' to match with type in DB*/
    }
  },
  {
    $sample: { /** Picks some random 3 docs (Sometimes a single doc can be repeated) */
      size: 3
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      localField: "categoryId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "categoryId"
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q-YgOdfZ0Wz)

**Ref :** [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/index.html)

**Note :** So `$sample` can get the job done, but it has few limitations read through the doc for more info. Use [$explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/index.html) to check if your query is performing well or not, In any case if `$sample` is not working for you, then you can actually use `$skip` & `$limit` to get this job done.

Let's say if you can auto generate some number at least 3 less than collections size for `skip` & skip those docs to eventually do `limit` of `3` on remaining docs. You can have a sort in between `skip` & `limit` - such way do test this for better uniqueness. Check this : [skip-and-limit-in-aggregation-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160037/skip-and-limit-in-aggregation-framework) - Usually this used for pagination but might help you in least case.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I actually wrote this one after googling and reading docs, but lost to converting id to ObjectId().